# OpenSSL version in the SONOS Self-Test Suite

Tags: sonos

I am trying to run the latest SONOS Self-Test Suite against a revised version of our API. I'm running macOS Sierra Version 10.12.4. The built-in (and remarkably difficult-to-remove) version of OpenSSL is `0.9.8zh`.

I have been able to install OpenSSL `1.0.2k` and override the path to be the default OpenSSL version, as shown by:

```
> openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

> which openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
```

Executing `python suite_selftest.py` returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "suite_selftest.py", line 36, in <module>
    import ssl_validation
  File "/XXX/sonostest/smapi/content_workflow/ssl_validation.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sslyze import sslyze
  File "../../sonos_sslyze-1.1.0.dev_r293552-py2.7.egg/sslyze/sslyze.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "../../sonos_sslyze-1.1.0.dev_r293552-py2.7.egg/sslyze/plugins/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "../../sonos_sslyze-1.1.0.dev_r293552-py2.7.egg/sslyze/plugins/PluginCertInfo.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "../../sonos_sslyze-1.1.0.dev_r293552-py2.7.egg/sslyze/utils/ctSSL/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "../../sonos_sslyze-1.1.0.dev_r293552-py2.7.egg/sslyze/utils/ctSSL/load_openssl.py", line 99, in <module>
```

Is the Self-Test Suite directly using `/usr/bin/openssl`? Is there any way I can override or change the path it's using?

Answer (score 0):

The self-test uses the open source SSLyze tool, and SSLyze loads the OpenSSL libraries (crypto and ssl library). When loading the libraries on OS X, the code looks first into the current directory and then calls Python's find_library(). Here is another stackoverflow about where Python searches for libraries:

[Which paths does python ctypes module search for libraries on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148387/which-paths-does-python-ctypes-module-search-for-libraries-on-mac-os)