# PyUSB, No backend available. How to specify custom location of libusb?

Tags: python, macos, usb, libusb, pyusb

System setup

- M1 Mac
- Brew installed libusb `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libusb/1.0.24/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib`
- Anacada python 3.10

The *No backend available* problem see be a known [issue](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/355) with newer python and ARM-based Macs. I am failing to arrive at a solution from that link.

I would like to place a copy of *libusb* in the project folder and specify that as the backend.

**Question:**
How do I specify the location of *libusb-1.0.0.dylib* in as a custom backend in find()?

```
>>> from usb.core import find
>>> f = find(find_all=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/vincentdavis/opt/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 1309, in find
    raise NoBackendError('No backend available')
usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available
```

I should be able to do something the code below based on this post [LINK](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/360#issuecomment-812802678).

```
backend = usb.backend.libusb1.get_backend(find_library="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libusb/1.0.24/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib")

f = find(backend=backend, find_all=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

```
import usb.core
import usb.backend.libusb1
backend = usb.backend.libusb1.get_backend(find_library=lambda x: "/usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so")
dev = usb.core.find(..., backend=backend)
```

From: https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst

**Alternative**

Try putting instead the contents of /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libusb/1.0.24/lib/ into **/usr/local/lib** and it should work.

This is one of the paths searched by find_library() of the Python ctypes module on Mac OS (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31148541/18197137)

Comment: This was just what I needed to resolve a fusee-launcher issue (https://github.com/Qyriad/fusee-launcher/issues/25), thanks!